# How can I achieve a strong and reliable bond between wood and copper/brass for my wooden stick production?

Tags: wood, woodworking

I am a producer of wooden [canes](https://canelaza.com/walking-canes/), but some of my customers have complained about the loose and insecure connection between wood and copper/brass. I want to address this issue and achieve a strong and reliable bond between wood and copper/brass.

Can you provide guidance or tips on achieving a durable and dependable bond between wood and copper/brass for my wooden stick production?

[image]

Comment: What do you use at the moment? And how are the two parts shaped to fit together?

Comment: It depends on the details of the current metal cap and in particular how determined you are to keep the precise shape of the current metal cap, or whether you're prepared to add screw holes, crimps, or an additional fitting (such as a thread). Something mechanical like that is probably better than glue.

Answer (score 2):

The stock answer is to increase surface contact area. For example, marrying to flush surfaces is inefficient as it allows for little protection against sheer stress.

A simple solution would be to drill a hole in both surfaces, and tap them for a screw thread. Glue a threaded rod into the wooden part using epoxy or two part resin, and then simply screw the metal part on to the thread.